# How to remove numbers in a string in Tcl using regsub?

Tags: regex, tcl

I would like to remove the numbers in a string but wish to remain the words that contain numbers. For example:

```
set a "t0day 1s a 234 5unny d4y 123"
```

The expected output:

```
t0day 1s a 5unny d4y
```

I have tried as below, but it is not working:

```
regsub -all {[^0-9]} $a " " a
```

Comment: If possible, please rewrite this question into: "What regex can I use to match words containing only numbers?" or similar, since your question seems to have little to do with Tcl.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Tcl's regular expression syntax is slightly uncommon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not really doing what you think it is doing. `[^0-9]` matches everything but numbers, so what will happen is that everything will get deleted and leave out numbers. What you probably want to do is:

```
regsub -all {\y[0-9]+\y} $a "" a
```

This will remove numbers from the string if they are by themselves. You will have a few trailing spaces though, and for that you can use:

```
set a [string trim $a]
```

after regsub-ing.

The `\y` ensures that there's no word character before or after the number, so that the `0` in `t0day` will not be removed.

Comment: Thanks. I have got it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to put [word-boundary anchors](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M76) in those regexps.

```
regsub -all {\y[0-9]+\y} $a " " a
```

That'll leave you with a triple space in some cases (which might or might not matter to you, but is trivial to clean up) but it won't substitute in the middle of words.